# Magento2 default google recaptcha is not working with onestep checkout

Tags: magento2.4.3, onestepcheckout, captcha, recaptcha, google-recaptcha

Magento default & mageplaza google recaptcha is not working when we using it with onestep checkout.

We are using AHEADWORKS onestep checkout module.

**Issue1 with invisible recaptcha:** There is no error on checkout but once we place an order then it redirects the customer to the cart blank page.

**Issue2 with visible captcha** The visible captcha is not showing on checkout page.

Any workaround or solution would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try disabling full page cache. this may be cache issue, or try change magento2 default theme.

Comment: @ZahidH I tried both of them but still not working.

Comment: Did you configure google recaptcha?  also check logs

Comment: Yes, I configured the google recaptcha & as I said there is no error on the frontend or logs.

Comment: @DeepakKumar any solution on this ?? I am facing the same issues.

Comment: Please check the recent posted answer. You might get some ideas to fix the issue at your end as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is fixed.**

We found the issue after disabling the installed third party modules one by one & the issue was only with the one-step checkout extension. It's overridden template was conflicting on the checkout page. Now the issue has been fixed after fixing the checkout template conflict.